# UPDATE with variables to renumber column gives syntax error

Tags: mysql-8.0

Searching for a way to renumber a column within mysql, I've found multiple articles showing the same approach:

- [Renumbering an Ordering Field in MySQL](http://paulwhippconsulting.com/blog/renumbering-an-ordering-field-in-mysql/)
- [How to update a MySql column with ascending numbers](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1733-how-to-update-a-mysql-column-with-ascending-numbers)

among others.

But trying it on my table I get a syntax error.

```
mysql> SET @rankStart = 10;
mysql> SET @rankInc = 10;
mysql> UPDATE fileFileTbl SET rank = (@rankStart := @rankStart + @rankInc) ORDER BY `rank` ASC;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank = (@rankStart := @rankStart + @rankInc) ORDER BY `rank` ASC' at line 1
```

The command looks identical to the articles posted.  What am I missing?

Here's the table (with some columns omitted):

```
CREATE TABLE `fileFileTbl` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fileEngineId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rank` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `fileName` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT 'newfile',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fileEngineId` (`fileEngineId`,`rank`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

System is Centos 8, with mysql as:

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.17 for Linux on x86_64 (Source distribution)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rank is a reserved word so you can it use only with backticks
**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE `fileFileTbl` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fileEngineId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rank` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `fileName` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT 'newfile',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fileEngineId` (`fileEngineId`,`rank`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO fileFileTbl VALUES (NULL,NULL,0,'test1'),(NULL,NULL,0,'test2'),(NULL,NULL,0,'test3');

SET @rankStart = 10;
SET @rankInc = 10;
UPDATE fileFileTbl SET `rank` = (@rankStart := @rankStart + @rankInc) ORDER BY `rank` ASC;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM fileFileTbl;

| id  | fileEngineId | rank | fileName |
| --- | ------------ | ---- | -------- |
| 16  |              | 20   | test1    |
| 17  |              | 30   | test2    |
| 18  |              | 40   | test3    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/18)

Comment: In further testing, if `fileEngineId` is not blank and equal to '4' and there's, an entry with rank 21, the renumber fails with `Duplicate entry '4-30' for key 'fileEngineId'`.  I suppose it first tries to renumber 4:21 to be 4:30, which fails the UNIQUE constraint.  Any suggestions?

Comment: i cqan't reproduce your problem see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/19,, you have to insert unique data, that you can acomplish by source code or by INSERT TRIGGER

Comment: change `fileEngineId` to all the same value, eg, '1'.  Then the error happens.  The fiddle is updated: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/20

Comment: as i already said, you must check the uniqueness of the inserts by a) do it in your code or b Write a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER that ckeck if there is already a 1:0 if you add CONSTRAINTS you also have to make sure not to violate them.

Comment: I wrote a trigger for you with your example,.https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/21

Comment: Thank you.  That's very helpful.